# Mongoose convert aggregate function to Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mongoose, sequelize.js

How to convert this Mongoose code to Sequelize?

```
     Model.aggregate()
        .match({
          _deal: this.deal._id
        })
        .group({
          _id: '$tier',
          count: {
            $sum: 1
          }
        })
        .exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.
Maybe will help somebody

```
Model.findAll({
  where: {
    deal_id: deal.id
  },
  attributes: ['tier', [db.sequelize.fn('count', db.sequelize.col('tier')), 'count']],
  group: ['Model.tier']
})
```